# PHP sorting multi-dimensional arrays based on values but getting unexpected results

Tags: php, database, mysqli, multidimensional-array

so I've been scratching my head about this one for a while and almost there but still getting unexpected results.

So I have a database containing the following data

```
username |  level1    |  level2    |  level3
user1    |  39.76072  |  79.41869  |  151.2955
user2    |  39.80072  |  80.73846  |  270.6498
user3    |  39.84072  |  80.81845  |  83.41801
user4    |  39.85321  |  80.90525  |  88.31719
user5    |  Zero      |  Zero      |  Zero
```

I've been trying to put these into a multi-dimensional array in order from the lowest to the highest but have really been struggling. These are basically level times and I'm trying to create a leaderboard.

I assume the problem is that the level columns are not INT but rather CHAR

I am currently trying the following

```
function order_by_time($a, $b) {
    return $b["Level".$_POST["level"]] < $a["Level".$_POST["level"]] ? 1 : -1;
}


$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT userName, Level".$_POST["level"]." FROM table");
$results = array();
$unranked = array();
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($line["Level".$_POST["level"]] == "Zero"){
        $unranked[] = $line;
    } else{
        $results[] = $line;
    }
}
usort($results, "order_by_time");
$results = array_merge($results, $unranked);
```

This works for level1 and for level2 but not for level3.
Level1 displays as it does in the aboce database example and so does level2 but the problem is so does level3 and that isn't the correct order.

it looks like its something to do with the number of characters before the decimal.

Any advice on how i can resolve this without touching the database? that isn't really an option as its already being used.

I'd really appreciate some help with this :-)

Comment: Can you show what the desired result is?

Comment: "I assume the problem is that the level columns are not INT but rather CHAR" No such thing in PHP. Everything is loosely typed and those numbers would be recognized as floats.

Comment: It seems like it would be better to add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query rather than sorting it in PHP.

Comment: @PatrickQ the desired result is for level1 and level2 to display as it is in the database as it is already in order from lowest to highest but level 3 should be 88.31719, 83.41801, 151.2955, 270.6498, Zero

Comment: Oh, I missed the part about not touching the db

Comment: It is unclear whether "without touching the database" means not adjusting the _query_ or not adjusting the structure of the database.

Comment: Instead of describing it in words, can you please update your question to include the actual desired result based on the given sample data?  What would the output of `$results` be?

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: @PatrickQ,  I can change the query. I just can't amend database field types and such. I've tried ORDER BY ASC but it gives me the same results.

Comment: @miken32 does it display level3 in the correct order?

Comment: With `$results = [["username"=>"user1", "Level3"=>"151.2955"], ["username"=>"user2", "Level3"=>"270.6498"], ["username"=>"user3", "Level3"=>"83.41801"], ["username"=>"user4", "Level3"=>"88.31719"]];` it works perfectly. But I've posted a better solution for you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't inject something from `$_POST` directly into an SQL query. That's how sites get hacked. In this particular case, I'd recommend setting a variable with that parameter cast to integer, and check its value as well:

```
$level = (int)$_POST["level"];
if ($level > 0 && $level < 4) {
    $query = $con->query("SELECT userName, Level$level FROM table");
} else {
    die();
}
```

As to your question, the simple solution here is to sort in the database. `ORDER BY Level$level` and you're done.

```
$level = (int)$_POST["level"];
if ($level > 0 && $level < 4) {
    $query = $con->query("SELECT userName, Level$level FROM table ORDER BY Level$level");
} else {
    die();
}
$results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If that's not possible for some reason, what you've got there should be working just fine according to my testing. But it's rather hacky, especially pulling information from `$_POST` to a custom function. Instead just use PHP's built-in abilities to work with multidimensional arrays.

```
$level = (int)$_POST["level"];
if ($level > 0 && $level < 4) {
    $query = $con->query("SELECT userName, Level$level FROM table");
} else {
    die();
}
$results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$usernames = array_column($results, "username");
$times = array_column($results, "Level$level");
array_multisort($times, SORT_ASC, $results);
```

Comment: hey thanks man, this did work but it stores the username as the index. I need the index as this is what i am using to determine the users position on the leaderboard.

So this gives me for level1

[user1]=>39.76072

I need it to be 

[0]=>array(user1, 39.76072)

this way i can use the index to say that the players position

unless there is a more elegant way to do it using what you've show above

Comment: Wouldn't the order in the array determine that? Anyway if that's the way you want it set up, it should have been working with what you already had, or with database ordering.

Comment: strangely it didnt. it would get ... confused if the amount of digits before the decimal are not consistent so it would put 270.6498 as a faster time than 83.41801

either way i found what works (i currently think) is you're solution above with 

'$row = array();
foreach($results as $tmp){
    $row[] = array(key($results), $tmp);
    next($results);
}'

Comment: ORDER BY in the query is giving me results that are all over the pace. the other option worked fine just as the first option you gave me. what confuses me though is that none of them seem to work in a function 

`function sortIt($level){
      the code you suggested
}`

any idea why? I thought i may as well stick it in a function and make it re-usable as i will have to use it a few times

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark as accepted and then ask a new question. Though I would suggest reading up on functions first. Specifically how to return values from them.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of that this wouldn't work would be that there are some leading or trailing spaces in the values that are preventing them from being converted to numbers for the comparison.

If you're just echoing them out in HTML, you probably wouldn't see the spaces, but you'll see them if you `var_dump` the variable. The normal behavior of PHP is to compare numeric strings as numbers, but it won't work that way if there are extra spaces.

```
$test = '151.2955' > '83.41801';
var_dump($test); // true
$test = '151.2955 ' > '83.41801 ';
var_dump($test); // false
```

Try trimming the values.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT userName, TRIM(Level3) AS userValue FROM table");
```

The expression is aliased, so refer to it in your PHP code as `$row['userValue']` rather than using the value from `$_POST`. If this does work, it may also let you use `ORDER BY` in MySQL. I'm not really sure if whitespace has the same result there as it does in PHP. I think you'll need to cast the column to a numeric type for it to sort properly regardless of spaces. It's unfortunate that you can't alter the table to store the number as a number.